# Angular 4 - How to upload files to backend?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to upload multiple files to spring boot server from angular 4 front end.

```
 selectedFile : File []  = [];
  filesToUpload: File[] = [];
  selectedFileNames: string[] = [];

  readURL(fileInput) {
    // this.detectFiles(fileInput);
    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++)
    {
        this.selectedFile.push(fileInput.target.files[i]);
    }
    console.log(this.selectedFile)
}

onUpload2(){
    const fd = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++){
      fd.append('fileseee',this.selectedFile[i],this.selectedFile[i].name);
    }

    this.questionService.uploadImages(fd).
    subscribe( 
      (data: any) => {
           }
         )
   }



uploadImages(fda){
  console.log(fda);
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+"/imageUpload112",fda)
  .map((res : Response) => res);
}
```

The back end spring boot code works fine with postman. The error showing is

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is
[org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause
```

My Postman details:

[image]

spring controller code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/imageUpload112")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("fileseee")MultipartFile[] fileStream)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    String bucketName = "mcqimages";
    String status = "";
    String url = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < fileStream.length; i++) {
        MultipartFile file = fileStream[i];

        try {
            checkFileExtension(file.getName());
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("-YYYY-MM-dd-HHmmssSSS");
            DateTime dt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
            String dtString = dt.toString(dtf);
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

            BlobInfo blobInfo =
                    storage.create(
                            BlobInfo
                                    .newBuilder(bucketName, fileName)
                                    .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), Role.READER))))
                                    .build(),
                            file.getInputStream()
                    );

            System.out.println(blobInfo.getMediaLink());
         // status = status + "You successfully uploaded file=" + file.getOriginalFilename();
            url= url+ blobInfo.getMediaLink() + ",";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = status + "Failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: can you share your postman request details?

Comment: i have added a screenshot

Comment: i can recommend you this article. good and clear example i guess.
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-upload-component-with-express

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure, that both Spring controller and Angular web page are using the same headers "multipart/form-data"

Example of Angular upload method:

```
return this.http.post(`/file`, formData, {
  headers: {
    'enctype': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=request-boundary',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Example of Spring Controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/file", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ImageResponse uploadImageFile(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile[] imagefiles) {
    return imageService.saveImageFiles(imagefiles);
}
```

Comment: yea i know what you mean . but the problem here is multiple files uploading part :/

Comment: @sachinthahewawasam, in this case, please add to the question your Spring controller code. It will help to determine an issue.

Comment: @sachinthahewawasam, the spring error directly tells you that it doesn't see a file. Postman sends these headers implicitly. In the angular, you should specify them explicitly.

Comment: look , i have added the spring controller @VadymVL

Comment: @sachinthahewawasam, try to add `consumes = "multipart/form-data"` to your `@RequestMapping` and check your upload.

Comment: @sachinthahewawasam, have you did it along with sending headers from your Angular method?
`headers: {
    'enctype': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=request-boundary',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }`

Answer (score 0):

When you push your file to storage aren't you sending headers?

I do that using this:

```
pushFileToStorage(file: File) {
    const body: FormData = new FormData();
    body.append('file', file);
    const headers = new Headers({
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    });

    return this.http.post(this.urlEndpoint, body, { headers })
      .map(respuesta => {
        console.log(respuesta.json());
        return respuesta.json();
      });
  }
```